# Can't locate Flash Player in WMI win32_product table

Tags: wmi, flash, wmi-query

How come the Macromedia Flash Player isn't present in the WMI win32_product table? The Flash Player is installed on the machine where I'm executing the query.

I'm trying to execute the following query:

```
Select * From win32_product where name like '%Flash%'
```

Is there any other way to get the version of any installed Flash Player. This project is developed in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Win32_Product` class only represents products that are installed by [Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185688(VS.85).aspx). Looks like Flash Player uses another installation service.

Here's how you can determine the existence and version of the Flash Player ActiveX control (Flash Player for IE):

1. Try obtaining the `System.Type` object corresponding to the `ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash` ProgID. If you fail to get it, then the Flash Player is not installed. If you succeed, go to step 2.
2. Create an instance of the obtained `Type` object.
3. Call the `GetVariable` method of the obtained object with the "$version" parameter. This will give you the Flash Player version string in the form "OS major,minor,release,build", e.g. "WIN 10,0,22,87".

Something like this (*Disclaimer: I don't know C# well, so this code may be lame*):

```
Type tFlash = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash");
if (tFlash != null)
{
    object FlashPlayer = Activator.CreateInstance(tFlash);
    string version = (string) tFlash.InvokeMember("GetVariable",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
        null, FlashPlayer, new Object[] {"$version"});

    Console.WriteLine(version);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Flash Player is not installed.");
}
```

Note that this approach requires that you build your application for the x86 platform, since the Flash Player is currently 32-bit only and you cannot interact with its ActiveX object from 64-bit code.